# Dijkstra's algorithm on three dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, dijkstra

I really cannot figure out how to implement this even in psuedo-code. The user enters in something like this:

```
[
  [
     [0,1]
  ],
  [
    [5,6],[7,8]
  ],
  [
    [91,17],[18,42]
  ],
  [
    [20,54]
  ]
]
```

Basically this is a path where [0,1] maps to ([5,6] and [7,8]) each of which maps to ([91,17] and [18,42]) and so on, the cost is the distance between the points. The starting point is [0, 1] and the ending point is [20,54]. There is always one starting point and one ending point, and all the points in the previous index map to the points in the next index.

How do I implement Dijkstra's algorithm for this kind of data structure?

This image may help (not to scale):
[image]

Green is the start and red is the end.

Comment: I've read it thrice but I still don't know what that array means. Is it paths?

Comment: @ThomWiggers I put a slightly better explanation in. yes, it's paths, the cost is the distance.

Comment: @KthProg no you didn't ;-)

Comment: @Alnitak I put in an even better explanation now, I'm not sure what I'm not explaining.

Comment: @Everyone, I added an image

Comment: That does help, somewhat.  If this is plain 2D space, can't you just collapse the inner pairs into their (1D) Euclidean distance?

Comment: Well yeah, the cost function is their distance, but I'm not sure how to implement the algorithm for this structure. That's the point of the whole question.

Comment: Rather than trying to figure out how to run the algorithm on this strange data structure, why not focus on converting this structure into one you can deal with?

Comment: Because JavaScript which I'm using only has two basic data structures: a map, and an array. So there is no way to convert it really. I may be able to make an object that mimics this layout... maybe that is a better idea.

Comment: @JamesMontagne That seems to be doing the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the given array is two dimensional if we considered the entry in the array as a pair `(x, y)`.

The basic idea is build the graph, assign the cost of edges, and then apply the standard Dijkstra's algorithm.

Building the graph:

Make 2 hash tables `H` and `Q` where `H([x,y])` maps a vertex `(x,y)` to a number between `0` and `n - 1`, and `Q` maps an integer between `0` and `n - 1` to a vertex `(x, y)`. `n` is the number of vertices in the graph. We can find `n` easily by looping over all the vertices in the given `2d` array. Let's call the given array `A`

Pseudo-code of hashing:

```
n = 0
for(i = 0; i < length of A ; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < length of A[i]; j++)
            H[A[i][j]] = n
            Q[n] = A[i][j]
            n++
```

Notice that `A[i][j]` is actually a pair of integers, so the key of `H` should be a pair of integers.

Now we can build the graph considering vertices as numbers between `0` and `n - 1`. We can represent the graph as an [adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list)

Psudo-code of constructing the graph:

```
array g[n][]                              //-- adjacency list of the graph
for(int i = 0; i < length of A - 1; i++)  //-- notice the "-1"
    for(int j = 0; j < length of A[i]; j++)
        for(int k = 0; k < length of A[i + 1]; k++)
            g[ H[A[i][j]] ].insert (H[ A[i + 1][k] ])
            g[ H[ A[i + 1][k] ].insert( H[A[i][j]] )     //-- assuming the graph is undirected
```

By doing this, we have built the graph. Now we can apply the standard Dijkstra's algorithm on the graph `g`. To find the cost of an edge between two vertices `u` and `v` we can use the hash table `Q` in order to get the coordinates of `u` and `v`. Then the cost of the edge is the [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between points `Q[u]` and `Q[v]`.

Pseudo-code for cost of an edge between two vertices `u` and `v`

```
cost(int u, int v)
    return Euclidean_distance(Q[u], Q[v])
```